# Writing at the bottom of JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have a `JScrollPane` and a `JTextArea` (editable) with 10 rows. I want the first user input to appear at the bottom of the `JTextArea` and the most recent input should push the previous input upward. To achieve this I use `textArea.setMargin(new Insets(x,0,0,0));` and everything works as it should - except that my second input will toggle the `JScrollPane`.

How can I start at the bottom of the `JTextArea`  and only enable scrolling when the entire original viewport is filled?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you could add the `JTextText` onto a `JPanel` with another `JPanel` which acts a filler, causing the `JTextArea` to occupy the smallest space it actually needs.

I did this by using `GridBagLayout` to force the fill to occupy the most of space it could...

[image: Scrolling]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestTextArea {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTextArea();
    }

    public TestTextArea() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(new TestPane()));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea ta;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            JPanel filler = new JPanel();
            filler.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            add(filler, gbc);

            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 0;
            ta = new JTextArea(1, 20);
            add(ta, gbc);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have not enough to go on. Could you please elaborate? And you understand that the last lines I enter are already visible, always. It's just the immediate toggling of the JScrollPane that bugs me.

Comment: @user2651804 Perhaps you should consider providing [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we're both on the same page

Comment: Here are two screencasts that should illustrate my problem: http://screencast.com/t/dBPyVAwfT and http://screencast.com/t/ZolTEEADS

Comment: Don't know if manipulating the caret is the answer or not, but don't use don't use textArea.getText().length() as this is not efficient since the Document needs to be parsed to create a text String. Instead you can just use `textArea.getDocument().getLength()`. @user2651804, if you want other people to help, the images should be part of the question, not a comment so everybody can see the images.

Comment: @camickr someone rapped me over the fingers for posting visuals as screencast in the Question once. And I don't know how to post it as an actual image, lol.

Comment: GridBagLayout scares me away.. but the code works. It'll take some time for me to study it, but I guess I should be learning some new tricks anyway. Thanks for the code!

Comment: +1 you are a pragmatic programmer rather than mad, @user2651804 im scare about the power of `GridBagLayout`

Comment: I was thinking if it can be done more easily with `JEditorPane/TextPane`

Comment: @nachokk I can't think of way to do with a `JTextArea`, `JEditorPane` might be able to do it, may be through the use of a HTML based document or custom `Document`...but about there, `GridBagLayout` looks so much simpler...

Comment: @nachokk, This approach is probably the simplest, although I would use a BorderLayout on the panel and then just add the text area to the SOUTH. There is no need for the second component. You can use a custom view for the JTextPane. Not sure how simple it is but check out stanislavl's [Center Text Vertically](http://java-sl.com/tip_center_vertically.html). You just need to change the "offset" calculation in the `CenteredBoxView` to use `offset = (targetSpan - textBlockHeight);`

Answer (score 1):

> To achieve this I use textArea.setMargin(new Insets(x,0,0,0)); and everything works as it should - except that my second input will toggle the JScrollPane.

Well I would guess that you would need to reset the margin every time you add text to the text area to take into account the new preferred size of the text area in relation to the size of the scroll pane.

You should be able to add a DocumentListener to the text area and make your adjustment whenever text is added to the Document.

Comment: I have 2 problems with that: 1) I've heard that instanciating objects is a high-cost task for the program: And the program will be adding a lot of text automatically!
2) I don't set the preferred height of the textarea. I don't specify number of rows either: It's height is determined by preferred high of neighbouring components in a BorderLayout. Does this not mean that the preferred height has nothing to do with scroll pane toggling?

Comment: The preferred height has "everything" to do with the scrollbars appearing. Presumably the value of "x" basically represents the height of 9 lines of text. When you add a single line of text the preferred height is still less than the size of the scrollpane. When you add a second line of text the preferred height becomes greater than the size of the scrollpane so the scrollbar appears. 1) creating objects is not an issue. Your can even write the code to reuse the same Insets or only create a new Insets when the "x" value actually changes.

Comment: What you're saying is if I have panel1 with preferredSize(0,0) and put panel2 with preferredSize(100,100) into panel 1, both my panels will have prefferedSize of (100,100)

Comment: If so, would my JTextArea also have a preferred size of the size it appears in when I run my program? (which I didn't set myself. But it's part of a BorderLayout; One of the elements in the layout has a preferred height that matches the displayed height of JTextArea)

Comment: And if I resize my window. Do preferred sizes change too? Because some layouts don't listen to preferred sizes, but maybe minimumSize instead. Are their preferred sizes then set to their MinimumSize?

Comment: @user2651804, I think I would forget this suggestion. It is more complicated than MadProgrammers solution. It has nothing to do with multiple components. It was an approach that would dynamically set the insets of the text area such that the insets would force the text to be painted at the bottom of the scroll pane.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that using margins and insets is the way to go because you are using layout adjustments to achieve text (content) functionality. This should be controlled by the `Document` object, which is what `JTextArea` makes its calls to regarding its content.

If you are calling `append` internally, then override it in a new class extending JTextArea:

```
public class Test {

static MyTextArea ta = new MyTextArea();
static int x = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ta.setRows(10);
        ta.setText("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        ta.setCaretPosition(ta.getDocument().getLength());

        JButton append = new JButton("Append");
        append.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ta.append("\n" + x);
                x++;
            }
        });

        JFrame frame= new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new JPanel(new BorderLayout()));
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(ta), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(append, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class MyTextArea extends JTextArea {

        @Override
        public void append(String str) {

            super.append(str);
            try {
                if (getDocument().getText(0, 1).equals("\n"))
                    getDocument().remove(0, 1);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are editing it manually, add a DocumentListener:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
        ta.setRows(10);
        ta.setText("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        ta.setCaretPosition(ta.getDocument().getLength());
        ta.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocListener());

        JFrame frame= new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new JPanel(new BorderLayout()));
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(ta), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class MyDocListener implements DocumentListener {

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

            final DocumentEvent de = e;

            Runnable pushUp = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    String t = null;
                    try {
                        t = de.getDocument().getText(de.getOffset(), de.getLength());
                        if (t.equals("\n") && de.getDocument().getText(0, 1).equals("\n"))
                            ta.getDocument().remove(0, 1);
                    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };       
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(pushUp);     
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}
    }
}
```

Note that all you need from the code are the inner classes, the rest is just so you can see it working. I also don't have information regarding the initial state of the text area. Here I just set the number of rows to 10 and the text to 10 empty lines. I'm also not sure what you're allowed to do in the text area. This solution assumes that you can't jump lines and each time you insert a line it's not blank and it follows the previous line.

Comment: Ah! Very understandable, very sneaky! Thanks for the answer ;-)