# Writing at the bottom of a TextArea with linewrap

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a console-like visual with text flowing from bottom to top.

I found a very useful solution for that right there:
[Writing at the bottom of JTextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623515/writing-at-the-bottom-of-jtextarea)

It works as for one point: this solution does not linewrap.
In the current implementation, if I append a long line at the end of the text, then it scrolls right. See an example here:
[image]

What I would like instead, is the "sentence" world to be linewrapped and therefore placed in the next line. And it should not scroll right.

I played around a bit, by adding:

```
        ta.setLineWrap(true);
        ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

But no effect was visible.
When I also added:

```
        ta.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
```

it linewrapped but now the text does not scroll down any longer...

Can you please help me fixing this issue?

Comment: What about `ta.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 1000));` restricting only the width.

Comment: `What I would like instead, is the "sentence" world to be linewrapped and therefore placed in the next line. And it should not scroll right.` - works fine for me using JDK8 on Windows 7. That is the text wraps as expected.

Comment: Hi Joop,When I try that, the text goes offscreen and does not scroll down any longer.

Comment: Thanks camickr, you are correct! After re-trying out, it seems that the text does linewrap normally, except for the few pixels below the right scrollbar.
When the right scrollbar is visible, then the screen creates a bottom scrollbar for scrolling below the right scrollbar. When the word is long enough, is does linewrap normally

Answer (score 0):

Tried **HTML**? Something along these lines:

```
jTextArea.setText("<html><body style='vertical-align:bottom;width:100%;height:100%;'>" +
                  text);
```

Answer (score 0):

After re-trying out, it seems that the text does linewrap normally, except for the few pixels below the right scrollbar. When the right scrollbar is visible, then the screen creates a bottom scrollbar for scrolling below the right scrollbar. When the word is long enough, is does linewrap normally/

Thanks camickr!